# How to do "And" condition in regex angular

Tags: angular, regex

Please help me with regex pattern. While filling form of description field, 1) if "double quotes" entered then show error message  2)while filling description field value if chars are less than 10 then show error message

```
 <div class="input-container">
        <textarea
          id="desc"
          name="desc"
          #desc="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)]="program.desc"
          aria-required="true"
          pattern="(?=\s*(\S\s*){10,})(?=^[^'\&quot;]*$)"
          required
        ></textarea>
      </div>

 <div *ngIf="desc.invalid && (desc.dirty || desc.touched)">
        <div *ngIf="desc.errors?.pattern">
          {{ msgDescMinLength }}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="desc.errors?.required">
          {{ desc}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Why do you ignore leading whitespace, but treat trailing whitespace as valid for your 10-character count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general gist would be to combine your "no double-quotes" requirement into the criteria for what matches the ten characters you're looking for.

```
^[^\"]{10,}$
```

This would only match input that's got at least ten characters, with no double-quotes.

But it looks like you're also trying to handle spaces in a special way. Based on your current regex, I'm going to guess that you're planning to "Trim" the input, but allow spaces within the trimmed text. In other words, `"  My shop "` fails because "My shop" has fewer than ten characters, but `" Bob's shop "` succeeds?

That gets more tricky, because you have to ignore whitespace up to the first non-whitespace character, then allow up to 8 characters that can be anything but double-quotes, then require another non-whitespace character, then ignore whitespace again. I think something like this should work.

```
^\s*[^\s\"][^\"]{8,}[^\s\"]\s*$
```